# Why does arcpy.da.Walk work differently when used with file geodatabase (gdb) and personal geodatabase (mdb)?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, personal-geodatabase

Why does [arcpy.da.Walk](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) give different output with identical File (GDB) and Personal (MDB) Geodatabases?

Example:

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1

`r'D:\SCRipt\New.mdb'` is a copy of   `r'D:\SCRipt\New.gdb'`

---

```
db = r'D:\SCRipt\New.mdb'
    walk = arcpy.da.Walk(db)
    for x,y,z in walk:
        print x
        print y
        print z
```

produces this output:

```
D:\SCRipt\New.mdb
[u'FORESTS']
[u'Layout10', u'Layout1']
D:\SCRipt\New.mdb\FORESTS
[]
[u'Vydel', u'Kvartal', u'Vydel_S', u'Vydel_L', u'Lesnich', u'Leshoz', u'Layout1_Vydel']
```

---

```
db = r'D:\SCRipt\New.gdb'
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(db)
    for x,y,z in walk:
        print x
        print y
        print z
```

produces this different output:

```
D:\SCRipt\New.gdb
[u'FORESTS']
[u'Layout1', u'Layout10']
D:\SCRipt\New.gdb\FORESTS
[]
[] ## <- Why?
```

Comment: Have you tested this code on a modern version of ArcMap? 10.4 is quite old and only partially supported by ESRI.  I would imagine most people using this forum are on at  least 10.6?

Comment: Thank's I'm going to try. But... People may use different version of ArcGIS with my scripts. All my scripts were tested on MDB and work without any problem with this format. Some days ago I tested one script on GDB and find the mistake. I debugged the code and discovered the sourse - Walk and listing functions. I wan't to know - is it a real problem, or it depend's of my software? Maybe there is a way I don't know to make the function work?

Comment: the same bug in 10.7 detected

Comment: I just tested on ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap 10.8.2, and `arcpy.da.Walk` gives the same results between file geodatabases and personal geodatabases with feature datasets.  I checked the Issues Addressed for 10.7, 10.7.1, 10.8, 10.8.1, and 10.8.2 for a defect being addressed, but nothing jumped out at me.